# Difference between features in the same vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, pyqgis-3, vector-layer, symmetric-difference

I have a vector layer containing 3 rows (see image2). Each row is a polygon. The blue polygon is number3 and the magenta polygon is number2 (see image1)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

I need to subtract the polygon that has the attribute `"number"=3` to polygon that has the attribute `"number"=2`.

How can I do it in PyQGIS?

I have tried something like this:

```py
import processing

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Langham_SPZs_v1_diss")[0]

outfn2 = "Langham_SPZs_final.shp"

layer2=layer.selectByExpression('"number"=2')

layer3=layer.selectByExpression('"number"=3')

processing.run("native:difference", {layer3, layer2, 'OUTPUT':outfn2})
```

Comment: Blue is number 3, magenta is number 2 - I have edited the main post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Field `number` is a string in your data. So you have to use `"number='2'"` as expression. And you should extract the selected polygon with number=2 since both polygons are in the same layer. Use this script:

```
import processing

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Langham_SPZs_v1_diss")[0]

outfn2 = "Langham_SPZs_final.shp"    

layer.selectByExpression("number='2'")

layer2 = processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures",
     {'INPUT':layer ,
      'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]

layer.selectByExpression("number='3'")

processing.run("native:difference",
    {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(),
             selectedFeaturesOnly=True),
     'OVERLAY':layer2,
     'OUTPUT':outfn2})
```

Comment: Depending on the desired result, it can be done with shorter code:
`import processing

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Langham_SPZs_v1_diss")[0]
layer.selectByExpression("number='3'")

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:difference", { 
    'INPUT' : layer, 
    'OVERLAY': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True),
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    })`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [`materialize()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsFeatureSource.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureSource.materialize) method.

```py
from qgis import processing

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Langham_SPZs_v1_diss')[0]

outfn2 = "Langham_SPZs_final.shp"

layer.selectByExpression("number='2'")
layer2 = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.selectedFeatureIds()))

layer.selectByExpression("number='3'")
layer3 = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.selectedFeatureIds()))

processing.run("native:difference", {'INPUT' : layer3, 'OVERLAY' : layer2, 'OUTPUT': outfn2})
```

*Note:* this method is available since QGIS 3.0.

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | 21. Cheat sheet for PyQGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#layers)